# How do I enable these control buttons on the Google Maps activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So my question is pretty straight forwards. I want to enable my Google Maps activity to display these control buttons on the screen and I am unable to find out how to do so. I have tried to using

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
```

but its not changing anything. Here is what I want to achieve: [image]

Comment: Can you update with the XML for the mapView?

Comment: Why tag your question with `google-maps-api-3` which is the Javascript API if your issue is about Java?